# Auto delete the input value

Tags: html, css, forms

For example, I have a text input with a value of "insert text here" like this:

```
 <input type="text" value="insert text here" />
```

When I click on the block of the input, then the text of "**insert text here**" will automatically disappear, but when the user cancel to write something there, the text will appear again.

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the HTML placeholder. [More here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Comment: Placeholder is great! Thanks! Solved!

Comment: you should mark the solution if below answers helped you. Mark anyone which suited you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE placeholder attribute
 `<input name="" type="text" placeholder="place holder text here."/>`

but it may not work in older browser. if you are for older browser as well than you should use javascrip/jquery for dealing with this problem.

```
<input type="text" class="userName" value="Type User Name..." />


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.userName').on('focus',function(){
    var placeHolder = $(this).val();
        if(placeHolder == "Type User Name..."){
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
    $('.userName').on('blur',function(){
    var placeHolder = $(this).val();
        if(placeHolder == ""){
            $(this).val("Type User Name...");
        }
    });

});
```

see deme  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/he6ho0vf/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this `placeholder` attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="insert text here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="insert text here">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "placeholder" attribute like so:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="insert text here" />
```

The placeholder text will be automatically deleted when typing something in the field

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0):

use a placeholder instead of value.

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="insert text here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Placehoder
but u need to be aware of Older versions of browsers, because it doesn't supports the place hoder

```
 <input type="text" value="some text"  placeholder="insert text here"/>
```

for older versions of browser u can use the below link and download the js

[link](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/)

Answer (score -1):

```
If you want compatible in all browsers then you can use this code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">

<p>Click the button to display the placeholder text of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").placeholder;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its just a copy paste of w3schools, you should explain it. it can also be achieved without javascript

Comment: Yes I know it just copy paste but it's solutions of problem.

Comment: @Nadeem You are also given solutions as copy paste you can check your code also

Comment: but y so lengthy thing, if u can achieve the same thing in just adding one atttibute to the same control. I think we are here to reduce the code and make the things efficient

Comment: Yes but I can explain everything here. If user can not understand.So i have explained

Comment: No issue, thanks for it. No hard feelings, was just making the things better